# Interpreting the results based on Granger Causality test

Tags: statistics, chi-square-test, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to use  Granger Causality test: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests.html

to assess whether "positivity score" affects value.

Here is the code I am using:

```
# Applying differencing
condensed_df['value'] = condensed_df['value'] - condensed_df['value'].shift(1)
condensed_df = condensed_df.drop(0)

# Running granger causality test
dct_pos_granger_causality = grangercausalitytests(condensed_df[["value", daily_avg_positive_score"]], maxlag = 4, verbose=False)
```

I have a total of 1,008 rows in the dataframe.

The results are as follows:

```
{1: ({'ssr_ftest': (0.005356633438031601, 0.941670291866298, 1003.0, 1), 'ssr_chi2test': (0.0053726552728412666, 0.9415686658133314, 1), 'lrtest': (0.005372640925997985, 0.9415687436896775, 1), 'params_ftest': (0.0053566334379265765, 0.9416702918669032, 1003.0, 1.0)})
 2: ({'ssr_ftest': (0.25177289420871873, 0.7774705403356538, 1000.0, 2), 'ssr_chi2test': (0.5060635173595247, 0.7764432226205071, 2), 'lrtest': (0.5059361470375734, 0.7764926721067107, 2), 'params_ftest': (0.25177289420872345, 0.7774705403356538, 1000.0, 2.0)})
 3: ({'ssr_ftest': (0.24649533124441178, 0.8638565929333925, 997.0, 3), 'ssr_chi2test': (0.7446779716230374, 0.862648253967841, 3), 'lrtest': (0.7444019401355035, 0.8627137383746588, 3), 'params_ftest': (0.2464953312443746, 0.8638565929334187, 997.0, 3.0)})
 4: ({'ssr_ftest': (0.6384235515822775, 0.6351740781255001, 994.0, 4), 'ssr_chi2test': (2.576816186064484, 0.6309354793595714, 4), 'lrtest': (2.57351178378849, 0.6315224927789413, 4), 'params_ftest': (0.6384235515823179, 0.6351740781254609, 994.0, 4.0)})}
```

I am struggling to interpret the results. Am I correct in thinking that, taking the 1st ssr_chi2test as an example, (0.0053726552728412666, 0.9415686658133314, 1), that 0.005 represents the test statistic, 0.94 the P-value and 1 the degrees of freedom?

If this is correct, then the null hypothesis can absolutely *not* be rejected, and potentially there is not enough data given that there is only one degree of freedom?

Any clarity would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(0.0053726552728412666, 0.9415686658133314, 1), that 0.005 represents the test statistic Yes,
0.94 represents the P-value - Yes.
and 1 the degrees of freedom? No.

And 1,2,3 and 4 are ordinary serial numbers and not, degree of freedom.

At 10% level of confidence, you need at least 2.71(value of Chi-square). You have computed the chi-square = 2.576 and therefore, the null-hypothesis is acceptable. Your assertion  - the null hypothesis can absolutely not be rejected- is valid in this particular case.

Comment: Hi Subhash, thank you for your help. How do you know that Chi-square must be 2.71, is this just a well-known fact?